# Can you vote for a Jew in non-Israeli politics?

Tags: halacha, chutz-laaretz, politics-government, voting

Perhaps I was misinformed, but I've heard that we are not supposed to directly have our hands in the politics of other countries. There's also a difference in overall culture and values of Western politics that one would unlikely be able to escape from if he or she were to be a part of the system.

So are we allowed to vote someone of Jewish descent into this system?

Comment: Many rabbis in past have held important and prestigious positions within the governments of the lands they've lived.

Comment: I think there's a duplicate of this already

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29044