# Which political system is the one most promoted/considered generally "correct"/optimal in the Torah & Jewish sources?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, tanach, malchut-royalty, politics-government

The Torah discusses kingship and G-d, blessed be He, and the problems that it could lead to. There is of course the infamous kritarchy (rule by Judges) and the results it produced.  However, I've seen someone claim that the Torah promotes an obscure system used in some place a long time ago, but I can't remember what its called. So I'd like to get an interpretation from the Jewish sources (in order to avoid this being an opinion piece): how should a government be conducted by humans according to the word of G-d, blessed be He.

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/481959/jewish/Left-or-Right.htm

Comment: @shmosel Not only did this answer absolutely nothing, but it in some sense might be counterproductive and the article not true in some aspects. Left-Right is not a useful distinction here also, but whatever. Perhaps my takeaway from the article is that I guess there is no universal perfect system for human governance, because whatever system we construct or try to derive, the sinful nature of man can sabotage it eventually over long periods of time and lead to chaos. Therefore, whatever is most suited to the local populace and will help them further follow the Torah is to be preferred.

Comment: The thing one must ask himself when voting is: "is this candidate beneficial for the Jewish Law and an advancement for mitzvos?" https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/135353/27180

Comment: Zohar says that the right is the side of light!

Comment: Sorry to have been so deeply unhelpful.

Comment: @shmosel Sorry, I didn't mean to be too harsh. The takeaway from the article was pretty useful in the sense that it doesn't seem to be possible to form a *perfect* system because humans as a collective will always since the fall be sinful through this acquired "nature", and so whatever we use will eventually be sabotaged internally by us given enough time. It'd then be the best just to follow the Torah.